# Usage of the term "what if any" in a question to a witness in court

Tags: rules-of-court, witnesses

I am not a lawyer - but I have a question inspired by the recent case of Depp vs Heard.

As heard in the courtroom (no-pun) - I feel like the usage of the term "what if any" its not a proper question - and should not be allowed in court.

In my opinion a sentence should be properly formed as normal people would - not opened ended - and subjected to the objections.

Why is this allowed - seems like an obvious and ordinary loop hole.

Comment: It’s an incomplete question (the “what if any”) so you would need more context.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The resident [linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts](https://english.stackexchange.com/tours) at ELU don't seem to have an issue with [using this phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+if+any%22).

Comment: A typical construction would be "What, if any, actions did you witness?"

Comment: Fair enough - as I prefaced it I am not a lawyer. I had never noticed the usage before - at least as heavy as in this trial. And as it appeared to me, the lawyer would ask a question - and it would be objected - ask it again in a different way - objected again - then throw the what if any. This time, the witness would respond - I think - only because of the context of the previous two objected questions.

Comment: The problem is that asking something like "What racist terms did he use?" assumes that he used racist terms, and thereby leads the witness into answering a certain way. By adding "if any," the examiner leaves open the possibility that he used no racist terms and avoids leading the witness to a certain answer.

Comment: @bdb484 That is a really good example and I understood it. Nevertheless, speaking from inexperience - I would have broken it down into two question: 1. Were there any racist terms used from "subject"? if yes - 2. What racist terms did he use? If I understand correctly - the jury is regular peeps like myself - the weird talk doesn't translate well IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I think most practitioners would agree that breaking it down into two questions like that is the better approach.

Comment: FWIW, as a lawyer, I did a double take asking myself, "what is confusing about that? It's ordinary language."

Comment: @ohwilleke This is just my opinion but 1. on a everyday conversation with friends and family - the construction of a sentence with "if any" does not come up often, and 2. in court, if the term is repeated question after question - just gets tiring. It is the same reason we are careful with word repetition i.e.: when we write an essay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no problem asking open-ended questions in court

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

First, a question can be inappropriate because the evidence that it seeks to introduce is inadmissible. Most commonly because it isn't relevant but also for hearsay, privilege, or any of several other reasons.

Second, the question may be "improper" within the meaning of [s41](https://legislation.nsw.gov.au/view/html/inforce/2020-07-01/act-1995-025?query=VersionSeriesId%3D%229cf426b5-c904-4ebf-bc7f-54c9ac0c8d4b%22%20AND%20VersionDescId%3D%22cfb4c9c1-0310-4e78-8086-e11a104b58c1%22%20AND%20PrintType%3D%22act.reprint%22%20AND%20(VersionDescId%3D%22cfb4c9c1-0310-4e78-8086-e11a104b58c1%22%20AND%20VersionSeriesId%3D%229cf426b5-c904-4ebf-bc7f-54c9ac0c8d4b%22%20AND%20PrintType%3D%22act.reprint%22%20AND%20Content%3D(%22cross%22))&dQuery=Document%20Types%3D%22%3Cspan%20class%3D%27dq-highlight%27%3EActs%3C%2Fspan%3E%2C%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%27dq-highlight%27%3ERegulations%3C%2Fspan%3E%2C%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%27dq-highlight%27%3EEPIs%3C%2Fspan%3E%22%2C%20Search%20In%3D%22%3Cspan%20class%3D%27dq-highlight%27%3EAll%20Content%3C%2Fspan%3E%22%2C%20Exact%20Phrase%3D%22%3Cspan%20class%3D%27dq-highlight%27%3Ecross%3C%2Fspan%3E%22%2C%20Point%20In%20Time%3D%22%3Cspan%20class%3D%27dq-highlight%27%3E01%2F07%2F2020%3C%2Fspan%3E%22#ch.2-pt.2.1-div.5) of the *Evidence Act 1995*:

> (1)  The court must disallow a question put to a witness in cross-examination, or inform the witness that it need not be answered, if the court is of the opinion that the question (referred to as a disallowable question)—
>
> (a)  is misleading or confusing, or
>
> (b)  is unduly annoying, harassing, intimidating, offensive, oppressive, humiliating or repetitive, or
>
> (c)  is put to the witness in a manner or tone that is belittling, insulting or otherwise inappropriate, or
>
> (d)  has no basis other than a stereotype (for example, a stereotype based on the witness’s sex, race, culture, ethnicity, age or mental, intellectual or physical disability).

Further, under s42, Leading questions *may* be disallowed if the court so rules.

**"Because it is open-ended" is not on the list.**